# Using .load() method inside .each() in jQuery not returning all html content

Tags: jquery

I am trying to iterate through list of hyperlinks in a page, load html content from every hyperlinked page and append it to a div in my current page.But the result is html content from only one of the page is loaded and appended to the div.How can I achieve the desired result.

Here is the code snippet that I am trying to achieve the result with:

```
$('th[scope="row"]').children("a").each(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    var tempDiv = $('<div id=\"loadedDiv\"></div>').appendTo('.someClass');
    var fullUrl = url+' '+'.tabClass';
    $("#loadedDiv").load(fullUrl);
});
```

Comment: You load them all but you also override them in each iteration. nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use class of `loadedDiv` not id as id's have to be unique.

In fact, a few tweaks to make the code quicker and more concise are

```
$('th[scope="row"]>a').each(function(){
    $('<div class=\"loadedDiv\"></div>').load(this.href + ' .tabClass').appendTo('.someClass');
});
```

Comment: My bad I was so naive, thanks for your quick and precise answer appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('<div id=\"loadedDiv\"></div>')
```

inside a .each loop is not a good idea.

you will get a few div with the same id.

[difference between id and class](http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/)

Answer (score 1):

You are creating new element with the same `id`, `loadedDiv`, on each iteration. This is invalid HTML since `id` attribute must be unique. Moreover, the `$("#loadedDiv")` will always fetch the same element, normally the first occurrence of `#loadedDiv` and you end up rewriting the contents of the same `div` over and over again.

You don't need to assign an `id` attribute to the newly created element if you create, append and load the contents using a chain.

```
$('th[scope="row"]').children("a").each(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    var fullUrl = url + ' .tabClass';
    $('<div/>').appendTo('.someClass').load(fullUrl);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use load, use $.get instead:

```
$.get(fullUrl, function(response) {

    $("#loadedDiv").append(response);

});
```